# Download Attachments From Outlook using Pythin Script

Tags: python, outlook, download, attachment

Now I wrote a code in which to run it every day to get the attachments of yesterday's emails.
when I run it the attachment isn't downloaded and instead I get a file named "@".

below is the code:

```
import win32com.client
import os
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("Inbox Subfolder Name") 
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
subject = message.Subject

# Get yesterdays date for the purpose of getting emails from this date
d = (date.today() - timedelta (days=1)).strftime("%y-%m-%d")
yesterdaydate=("20"+d)
print yesterdaydate

get_path_clt1 = "Folder Location" + yesterdaydate+"\\"

if os.path.exists(get_path_clt1):
    print " File Exists"
else:
    os.mkdir(get_path_clt1)


for m in messages:
    date = str(m.senton)
    date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date,'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
    messagedate=date_time_obj.date()

    if str(yesterdaydate) == str(messagedate) and (m.Subject == "Subject Name to compare") :
        print (message)
        print (messagedate)
        attachments = message.Attachments
        num_attach = len([x for x in attachments])
        print("test-1")
        for x in range(1, num_attach+1):
            print("test-in-1")
            attachment = attachments.Item(x)
            attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(get_path_clt1,attachment.FileName))
            print (attachment)
            print ("---------------------")
            break
        message = messages.GetNext()

    else:
        message = messages.GetNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to iterate over all attachment to get the number:

```
 num_attach = len([x for x in attachments])
```

Instead, you can use the [Attachments.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.count) property which returns an integer indicating the count of objects in the specified collection.

Second, make sure that you specify a valid filename:

```
 attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(get_path_clt1,attachment.FileName))
```

I'd suggest checking the `attachment.FileName` value before or generating your own.

Finally, you may check the [Attachment.Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.type?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm2371)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) property which returns an `OlAttachmentType` constant indicating the type of the specified object.

Comment: When I check the attachment.type I get "1" and the attachment.filename is "@"